# jQuery Dialog initially open at bottom of page

Tags: jquery

I'm having the rather common problem of a jQuery dialog (initialized and only visible upon a certain button click) somehow appearing on the Web page initially at the bottom, even prior to any button clicks, when it should be hidden.

Any ideas how to debug this? There are **no** JS errors.

On the page, the dialog would be initialized as follows (autoOpen=false),

```
onReady : function() {
    $('#pdf_box').dialog({
        resizable : false,
        autoOpen : false,
        modal : true,
        width : "350px",
        closeText : "Close dialog",
        close : function(event, ui) {
            //...
        },
        open : function(event, ui) {
            //...
        }
    });
```

Not sure where to start.

Comment: Any special CSS for `#pdf_box` that overrides jQuery's initial hidden styling? Any instances of `$('#pdf_box').dialog('open')` hiding somewhere? It would be good to see your markup for `#pdf_box`, any CSS related to it, and relevant code using the dialog.

Comment: Not sure, but do I need to run Firebug to see all the styles on #pdf_box?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `#pdf_box {display: none;}` to your CSS. It should prevent the html from being visible before jQueryUI loades.